# Use SubDivisionModifier in NPM Installation of THREE – Examples missing

Tags: javascript, npm, import, three.js

I want to use THREE.js and SubDivisionModifiers in a project.
I installed `yarn add three` THREE and reference it with 
`import * as THREE from 'three'` by exposing it to webpack with an imports loader. Now THREE is missing the subdivisions modifiers.

I was wondering how I could use SubDivisionModifer from THREE via npm installed modules. (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js)

In previous versions of THREE installations, there was also the `examples` folder included, where I could require the file from.
Now there is no examples folder.

Is there no way to install it properly?
For now I am at the point where I download the file manually and include it into my code, leaving it unmaintained...

Or is there another solution for this?

Cheers